# Trying to understand compilation error message

Tags: compile, adafruit

```
C:\Users\Field\Documents\Arduino\Adafruit_TCS34725-master\examples\tcs34725autorange\tcs34725autorange.ino:2:31: fatal error: Adafruit_TCS34725.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"

                               ^

compilation terminated.
```

exit status 1
Error compiling.

Comment: Did you try installing the library?

Comment: I got it, I goofed on installing the library.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a library, but it is either not installed, or is installed in the wrong location. A library, in this context, is code that supports a sensor or some other hardware or that accomplishes a task. We call them libraries because we can share and reuse them – like borrowing a book from a library.

It looks like you're trying to get the Adafruit TCS34725 color sensor going. The official source of the library is in the [Adafruit's GitHub repository for the TCS34725](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TCS34725) and there is a link at the bottom of the README for how to install a library. I'll bet that will get you back on track.

Comment: I got it, messed up on installing the library